# SOLR Exact match issue

Tags: solr, solrj

I have indexed my field in SOLR using field type "string". 
My field contains two values "APA" and "APA LN".
I have queried SOLR with **q=field:"APA"**.
With the above query i ma getting the results for both APA and APA LN.
I have to query SOLR to just get "APA".
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I presume that your field "field" is TextField or text_general. Can you change it to string and try again?

ie something like this

```
<field name="customfield" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It should not be happening for a type string. The most likely scenario is that you did not fully reindex or did not commit after reindexing.

You can check what your field actually contains in the Admin UI's [Schema Browser screen](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Schema+Browser+Screen) (press load term info).